# Weak property for subclassing UIStackView in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview, subclassing

I try to subclass UIStackView and add some controls that I want. I add a UIView as a container, and all the other views, such as UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView, etc, will be added into the container as a subview.

```
class UIButtonHeaderView: UIStackView {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var container: UIView!
    var titleLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - Initialization

    private func setUp() {
        // Set container.
        container = UIView()
        container.backgroundColor = .blue
        addArrangedSubview(container)

        // Set label.
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        container.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.text = "This is just a simple test!!"
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        titleLabel.textColor = .red
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setUp()
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but I have a trouble when I replace

```
var container: UIView!
var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

with

```
weak var container: UIView!
weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

I think the instance of class UIButtonHeaderView and its property (container and titleLabel) may have reference cycle issue, so I try to add weak in front of var, which causes my App crash.

Xcode told me that this line

```
container.backgroundColor = .blue
```

went wrong with the error message

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It seems that the line

```
container = UIView()
```

failed to create an instance of class UIView, so container is nil, which cause the App crash, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: Unrelated note: you generally shouldn't be subclassing `UIStackView` here. You should subclass `UIView` and add a `UIStackView` to that. This isn't really a "kind of stack view" (IS-A). It's a header view that happens to use a stack view for layout (HAS-A). You should generally avoid subclassing UIKit classes that weren't designed for it (if it were designed for subclassing, then the docs would generally include a section like "Subclassing Notes" or otherwise discuss subclassing).

Comment: Also, you should avoid the `UI` prefix for your class name; it will work but your class isn't part of UIKit, so it goes against convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Rob's answer you will still have a problem if you make your properties weak optional.

When you say this:

```
container = UIView()
```

There are no strong references to the newly created view, so it will immediately be released and `container` will become `nil` before you have an opportunity to add it to the stackview.

To overcome this issue you will need to use a local variable to hold the `UIView` reference until it is added as a subview; at this point the stack view will hold a strong reference and you can assign the reference to your `weak` property and let the local variable go out of scope without the view being released.

```
let newContainer = UIView()
newContainer.backgroundColor = .blue
addArrangedSubview(newContainer)
container = newContainer
```

And I agree with Rob's comment; subclassinf `UIStackView` probably isn't the right approach here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make optionals, because When we have a property that holds a weak reference to an object, it’s type should be an optional since it has the ability to become nil at runtime.

```
weak var container: UIView?
weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Khushbu's answer, this:

```
weak var container: UIView!
weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

means (via `weak`) that you want this value to become `nil` if the object is released, and also (via `!`) that you promise you will never access it if it is `nil`. These are conflicting.